# How to iterate over all table rows of each table in an HTML pages using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need the correct syntax to write two loops inside each other. First one to loop over each table in an html page with no ids or classes and the second one to iterate over each table row of the table specified by the first loop in jQuery.

Here is my jQuery but its not working probably wrong syntax.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table.rep').each(function(){
        $(this + ' tr').each(function{
            // change style of this tr
        });
    });
 });
```

Comment: Your table selector, `table.rep` finds all tables with the class "rep", but your question asks for "each table in an html page with no ids or classes".

Comment: don't forget to mark the answer that helped you with a tick, to "Accept" it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it like this (uses the jQuery context parameter to restrict the search for a `tr` element to the table:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table.rep').each(function(){
        $('tr', this).each(function{
             // change style of this tr
        });
    });
});
```

Or alternatively, like this (uses the `find` method to find elements that reside inside the element represented by the jQuery object you call the method on):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table.rep').each(function(){
        $(this).find('tr').each(function{
             // change style of this tr
        });
    });
});
```

You don't even have to nest loops depending on what you want to do, just looping over all table rows may suffice:

```
$('table tr').each(function(){
    // change tr style
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
$('table.rep tr').each(function(){
   ...        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('table.rep').each(function () {
            $(this).find('tr').each(function () {
            // Do your stuff
            });
        });
    });

 </script>
```